# Zend Framework won't let me include Google Maps API

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-maps

I'm experiencing this problem:

I want to add the Google Maps API to my Zend Framework application using the HeadScript Helper in the bootstrap:

```
$view->headScript()
->appendFile('/static/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js')
->appendFile('/static/js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.min.js')
->appendFile("http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAfINi4Ug3nkoREt524GX3ABSFqzY8bf3muCS1IE0M5aBPGVvVxRRzm1PmTbIwi_tXaNcSoONdlIx_sA");
```

But for some reason everytime I try this I get an empty alert box as error. The weird part now is, that when I insert the same script with the same key using plain HTML, so a "wrong key" from Google is not the problem:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAfINi4Ug3nkoREt524GX3ABSFqzY8bf3muCS1IE0M5aBPGVvVxRRzm1PmTbIwi_tXaNcSoONdlIx_sA" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I do not get that empty alert box. Did you experience anything similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue - ZF encodes the script URI automatically, so & becomes &amp;

Try

```
$view->headScript()
->appendFile('/static/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js')
->appendFile('/static/js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.min.js')
->appendFile("http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAfINi4Ug3nkoREt524GX3ABSFqzY8bf3muCS1IE0M5aBPGVvVxRRzm1PmTbIwi_tXaNcSoONdlIx_sA");
```

Comment: That did the trick for me! Thanks. I should have noticed that problem though... But thanks again :)

Comment: It's difficult to spot :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Weird I can only imagine it's a subtle difference in what's actually output - have you compared the output source of the two methods (using the headScript helper, and just hard coding the script tag) and seeing if there's any subtle difference?